# How to Deny permissions for newly created user in DDL Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ddl-trigger

I'm having trouble with a SQL DDL trigger for Create_User and I'm wondering if there is an issue with my syntax or something else I'm not seeing?

I have some tables in my database which are only available to a few users. The rest of the users in the database are not allowed to query these tables in any way. I've had no problems limiting current user permissions with

```
DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.SecretTable TO UserName
```

I'm trying to set up a DDL trigger to automatically run the Deny command when any new users are created. I am not the only one creating users in the database, so I won't be able to manually set permissions myself when new users are added.

With my trigger, I constantly receive the error

```
Cannot find the user 'UserName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

If I change the UserName placeholder to an already existing user in the trigger, I do not receive any errors - so it is not a permissions issue for my account. Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [NewUserCreation]
ON DATABASE
After Create_User
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @x xml = EVENTDATA();   
    SELECT UserName = @x.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(max)');
    DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ON dbo.SecretTable TO [UserName]

END
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [NewUserCreation] ON DATABASE
GO
```

Is there something I'm missing? The test results I've experienced so far seem to imply that the trigger is firing before the user account is actually created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to use dynamic SQL for this. Something like

```
create TRIGGER [NewUserCreation] ON DATABASE 
After Create_User
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @x xml = EVENTDATA();   
    declare @UserName Varchar(30)
    SELECT @UserName = @x.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(max)');
    declare @Cmd nvarchar(100)
    set @cmd = 'DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.SecretTable TO ' + QUOTENAME(@UserName)
    exec sp_executesql @cmd
END
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [NewUserCreation] ON DATABASE
GO
```

---

The reason your original code did not work is because your `select username` merely gave an alias `UserName` to the value returned from the select.  You are not able to use that column alias in the `DENY`.  Note that my example puts the value into a variable `@UserName`.  Then, I *build* a dynamic `DENY` statement and *externalize* the value of `@UserName` which is concatenated to the `DENY` command.

You can see this in action with this code snippet.  Assume I'm adding `NewUser` as a login and that is the value from the xml.

```
Declare @UserName varchar(100)
SELECT @UserName = (select 'NewUser')
declare @Cmd nvarchar(100)
set @cmd = 'DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.SecretTable TO ' + QUOTENAME(@UserName)
print @cmd
```

`DENY SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.SecretTable TO [NewUser]`

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help Scott. Is there a reason why dynamic sql worked here instead of a straight sql command?

Comment: @Eric - I added some extra information to my answer that will _hopefully_ answer your question.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks again. Previously I tried putting the value into a variable @UserName but experienced the same result. Building the dynamic query and externalizing the value was the part I was missing.